I'm running a google colab file, and I'm running into errors trying to import something
The beginning of the google colab file has us do
!pip install -e robosuite/
!pip install -e robomimic/
!pip install -e mimicgen_environments/
!pip install mujoco

These four apis are all under the colab_ws folder.
Now, whenever I need to use something from robomimic, I can import that fine
from robomimic.algo import RolloutPolicy

This line of code works fine. But this line
from robosuite.scripts import collect_human_demonstrations

Runs into an error
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-7058f4c5a961> in <cell line: 5>() 3 import imageio 4 ----> 5 from robosuite.scripts import collect_human_demonstrations 6 7 # create a thin wrapper around the model to interact with the environment

6 frames /content/drive/MyDrive/colab_ws/./robosuite/robosuite/scripts/collect_human_demonstrations.py in <module> 19 import robosuite.macros as macros 20 from robosuite import load_controller_config ---> 21 from robosuite.utils.input_utils import input2action 22 from robosuite.wrappers import DataCollectionWrapper, VisualizationWrapper 23

/content/drive/MyDrive/colab_ws/./robosuite/robosuite/utils/input_utils.py in <module> 7 import robosuite as suite 8 import robosuite.utils.transform_utils as T ----> 9 from robosuite.devices import * 10 from robosuite.models.robots import * 11 from robosuite.robots import *

/content/drive/MyDrive/colabws/./robosuite/robosuite/devices/init_.py in <module> 1 from .device import Device ----> 2 from .keyboard import Keyboard 3 4 try: 5 from .spacemouse import SpaceMouse

/content/drive/MyDrive/colab_ws/./robosuite/robosuite/devices/keyboard.py in <module> 4 5 import numpy as np ----> 6 from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key, Listener 7 8 from robosuite.devices import Device

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pynput/init.py in <module> 38 39 ---> 40 from . import keyboard 41 from . import mouse

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pynput/keyboard/init.py in <module> 29 30 ---> 31 backend = backend(name) 32 KeyCode = backend.KeyCode 33 Key = backend.Key

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pynput/util/init_.py in backend(package) 75 resolutions.append(RESOLUTIONS[module]) 76 ---> 77 raise ImportError('this platform is not supported: {}'.format( 78 '; '.join(str(e) for e in errors)) + ('\n\n' 79 'Try one of the following resolutions:\n\n'

ImportError: this platform is not supported: ('failed to acquire X connection: Bad display name ""', DisplayNameError(''))

Try one of the following resolutions:

Please make sure that you have an X server running, and that the DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the "Open Examples" button below.

I'm not sure why robomimic can import correctly but robosuite can't import. I've tried asking chatGPT about what to import but I'm not sure what to do.
